# RSpec: Best practice for testing ActiveRecord hooks with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, hook, factory-bot, rails-activerecord

I have a model, which should set itself a uuid when the *after_create* hook gets triggered.
Due I'm also using FactoryGirl to create Models inside specs, i'm struggling with the problem how the hook could be tested.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create: attach_uuid

  def attach_uuid
    self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
  end
end
```

And my spec looks like:

```
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, guid: nil)
user.save!
user.uuid.should_not be_nil
```

But apparently after the *save* call the hook and the method *attach_uuid* weren't triggered. Any ideas, how to test this kind of behavior after create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reload your object in rspec

```
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, guid: nil)
user.save!
user.reload.uuid.should_not be_nil
```